# What aircraft maintenance logs should I have available for a private checkride?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance, visual-flight-rules, checkride

I’m about to do my Private Pilot Checkride in my own plane. I’ve been trying to find a list of things that will be needed for the Checkride in the logbook, as I had thought it was an updated annual, ELT battery is within time, and all ADs are complied with. My CFI said he thought it needed other things like VOR checks in the last 30 days and transponder checks and more.  Is there a specific part in the FARs or somewhere that lists out exactly what it needed for VFR day/night flight as far as maintenance logs to keep the plane airworthy? I’m not talking ATOMATOFLAMES, but maintenance logs (aircraft, engine, prop) specific?

Comment: You should pose that question to the IA that does your annual.  Transponders require a perf check every two years.  30 day VOR checks are an operational check and only required for IFR use.  Since the PP checkride is a VFR flight, the requirements are the same for any other VFR flight so you'd want your paperwork to be in order same as if you were being ramp checked by an FAA inspector out on your travels.

Comment: I recommend looking at the following two videos which will cover almost everything you will need: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kr483zBbQKw and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVE-gIeZUpk&t=2s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is in the [Private Pilot ‒ Airplane Airman Certification Standards](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/acs/media/private_airplane_acs.pdf)

> Task   B. Airworthiness Requirements References   14 CFR parts 39, 43,
>   91; FAA-H-8083-2, FAA-H-8083-25

You should read and understand CFR §91.203, §91.205, §91.207, §91.209,  §91.213, and §91.215.

The DPE will want to know that the aircraft is legally permitted to operate in the airspace that you will be taking your practical test in.

They will check that the AR(R)OW documents are in the aircraft—Airworthiness Certificate, Current Registration, probably not Radio License since it is not likely your test will take you to another country, Operating Limitations, and current Weight and Balance. Operating Limitations would include placards; any documents required by STCs for installed equipment e.g. GPS or autopilot; and for newer aircraft flight manual (AFM) for that aircraft.

They will check the logbooks to make sure that the aircraft is legal maintenance-wise. Annual Inspection and 100-hour AD items obviously. Some 100 hour items can be signed off by the pilot e.g. Bendix switch check while others need to be signed off by an A&P e.g. muffler shroud inspection. Most A&Ps use a computer system that prints out a list of ADs and when they were complied with. It is a good idea to put a sticky-note on the annual and recurring ADs pages so you don’t waste time looking for them.

ELTs are usually checked at annual time, but they can get out of sync with the annual and they will check that. If you are taking the test in an aircraft with an electrical system, the transponder must be working and checked in the last 24 months. You don’t need a pitot-static check for a private checkride, but if you are going to file and fly IFR flight plan—as you will for your instrument rating you will need one.

If there is any inoperative equipment e.g. LORAN then it must be logged and marked.

ADSB isn’t required yet, but after January 1, 2020 if you fly in the covered areas your aircraft must have it installed. CFR §91.225.

On an instrument check-ride the DPE will want to see that the database is current if you have a GPS and that the VOR check has been done.

They will also check to make sure that your medical is current and that you have all of the endorsements necessary for the aircraft e.g. complex, high performance, tailwheel.

Answer (score 0):

From https://weflyimc.com/articles/f/aircraft-required-maintenance-inspections---acronym-aav1ate

```
**Airworthiness Directives 91.417(a)(2)(v)**
    Notifies aircraft owners and other interested persons of unsafe conditions and to specify the conditions under which the product may continue to be operated. They could be either one-time or recurring ADs.
**Annual Inspection 91.409**
    Every 12 calendar months. Can only be performed by an IAP (Inspection Authorized) mechanic. It also can substitute a 100-hr inspection.
**VOR 91.171**
    Every 30 days. Only required for IFR flights.
**100-hour Inspection 91.409**
    Only required if the aircraft is for hire.
    An aircraft can exceed its 100hr inspection only by up to 10 hrs while en route to a place where the inspection can be done. A special flight permit is not needed to fly those 10 hours, but the time must be logged in the maintenance record.
        If an inspection was due at 100hrs but the plane flew 105hrs before it was inspected, the next inspection will still be due at 200hrs.
**Altimeter, altitude reporting and static system 91.411**
    Every 24 calendar months
**Transponder 91.413**
    Every 24 calendar months
**ELT 91.207**
    Every 12 calendar months
    The regulation lists a lot of cases in which an ELT is not required, in which case maintenance is not required. Out of all items in that list there are two which might apply for flight training purposes:
        If engaged in training operations conducted entirely within a 50-nautical mile radius of the airport from which such local flight operations began.
        If temporarily removed  for no more than 90 days for inspection, repair, modification, or replacement, and in its place is a placard stating the removal.
```